# Jquery get form's html with values within div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have Got a div with two text area fields in it and , i have got a list of names where ; if you click on a name from the list it fills the first text area with the name and second text area with surname. This is done via jquery. 
I need to save all the content of the div with the values in to mysql and for this reason I have tried .html(), .text(), get().innerHTML, get(), content(), but even though it gets the html , it doesnt not get the text area html with value.

Comment: please show some code

Answer (score 0):

You need to grab the text area fields individually and then use `.val()` on them to get whatever will be entered in the field.

Comment: yes but for some reasons which i can not explain in here , this is the way I need to go with, think it like this way; you start typing in a text area when you save it should take form html with the text you put it in too; yes val does that but i need the whole form content.  for example  with .clone(); i can do what i want to append another part of the page but i need the content to be sent to mysql as a variable which append() doesnt give me this option

Answer (score 0):

ok i found a way to do it , when i mentioned that you click on a name from the list it sets the value of the text area; i used ,val(); , but instead i am now using .text(); and it allows me to get the value of it when i use .html(); to get the entire content with the form values. It may not be the best way but it does the job , I am open to suggestions